# Realm JS get records owned by a user with admin user

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-js

I am developing an app where I'm using Realm JS with fine graded permissions.
I think this is a really huge feature, and it is way better than using separeted realms.
I succesfully implemented record level permission, so I have one table with different records owned by different users.
Now what I am trying to do is to retrieve, server side and with admin credentials, all the records of a given table owned by a specific user.
Is that possible? I couldn't find anything helpful in the docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1 - filter by user**

This option depends on how you have your user roles setup and how you apply them to the objects. If you are using the default __User role created for each user and creating your permissions with that, providing you have the userId, you can query the permissions on the object to find the ones by the specific user.

e.g. get the first permission on the object

`let permission = object.permissions[0];`

The role name will be:

`let roleName = permission.role.name`

`roleName` will be in the format '__User:Id'

So, in theory you could query it as so (untested):

`realm.objects('YourObject').filtered(`permissions.role.name == '__User:${id}'`);`.

**Option 2 - login as the user**

The other option, and what I do, is login as the user. I use JWT Auth so I don't need a password. I generate a JWT token for the user and login. I can then open the realm as that user and only that user's records will be available.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks a lot for your suggestion! I am using JWT auth too, but honestly I don't like too much the second options. I will try with the second one, it seem a much better approach